# Как перенести текст с одной формы в другую

Tags: javascript, html, css

Прошу помочи.

Нужно создать дискуссию. Делаю при помощи форм.

1. Есть две формы.
   В первую форму вводим текст и нажимаем кнопку.
   После нажатия кнопки текст должен появиться в другой форме.
2. Создать вложенные дискуссии.

Реализовать нужно на **CSS**, **JavaScript**.

Пока сделал так:

```html
<form name="form2" id="form2" action="goto:form3">
  <p>Окно ввода</p>
  <textarea name="results" cols="40" rows="10">
    </textarea>
  <button name="submit" type="submit">
    <span style=" font-family: Arial, Helvetica; font-variant: small-caps; font-size: 12pt">
    Send</span>
    </button>
</form>
<form name="form3" id="form3">
  <p>Окно переписки</p>
  <textarea name="results" cols="40" rows="10">
    </textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Пока что вы толком ничего не сделали... Попытайтесь еще, а потом напишите на каком этапе у вас проблема и что не удается сделать и вам помогут

Comment: Вот так получилось. Теперь текст в форму 2 передается. Как теперь сделать вложеные дискусии?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
   function addTextR()
   {
    var a = document.getElementById('area_1').value;
    var template_text = a.toString();
    var txtarea = document.getElementById('area_2');
    var area2_text = txtarea.value;
    txtarea.value='';
    txtarea.value += template_text + area2_text;
    txtarea.focus();
   }
   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <textarea id="area_1"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="add" onclick="addTextR()"/>
  <textarea id="area_2"></textarea>
</div>

Comment: Сделайте нормальный воспроизводимый код, либо тут сниппет или же какой-нить codepn\jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function addTextR()
   {
    var a = document.getElementById('area_1').value;
    var template_text = a.toString();
    var txtarea = document.getElementById('area_2');
    var area2_text = txtarea.value;
    txtarea.value='';
    txtarea.value += template_text + area2_text;
    txtarea.focus();
   }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <textarea id="area_1"></textarea>
  <input type="button" value="add" onclick="addTextR()"/>
  <textarea id="area_2"></textarea>

</div>
</body>
```